# Date with in multiple Date Ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle, I have two tables, one table has a secvicepoint connection stamp history and other has reading data.

```
SRVCPOINT table

SPID    STARTDATE      STOPDATE       COMPANY
30      13-APR-2001   25-MAR-2002     UKPOWER
30      18-APR-2005   25-MAR-2006     UKPOWER


READING Table

READID SPID    READSTART      READSTOP
16      30     13-JAN-2001    12-APR-2001
23      30     13-APR-2001    25-JAN-2002
24      30     26-JAN-2001    24-MAR-2002
53      30     26-MAR-2002    25-MAR-2003
65      30     13-APR-2004    25-MAR-2004
74      30     20-APR-2005    25-MAR-2006
86      30     25-APR-2006    25-MAR-2007
```

I want to remove the reads which were taken during the period when the service was not given by UKPOWER, i.e. READID 16,53,65,86.
 I tried `READSTART not between STARTDATE and STOPDATE and READTOP not between STARTDATE and STOPDATE`,
But it ignores only reads 16 and gives 53,65,86. I mean it compares date with only first date range not with others.

can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you need the condition is something like

```
(ReadStart BETWEEN StartDate AND StopDate) 
AND (ReadStop BETWEEN StartDate AND StopDate)
```

For the row outside you can negate the same to this

```
NOT((ReadStart BETWEEN StartDate AND StopDate) 
    AND (ReadStop BETWEEN StartDate AND StopDate))
```

Or this

```
ReadStop < StartDate OR ReadStart > StopDate
```

Comment: I want to select other reads. cant delete the reads which were taken when UKPOWER was active.